# what is a simple open source cms with page view editing

Tags: open-source, content-management-system

I want to find a simple small open source cms and I like the idea of logging in, then being able to go to any website page and double click on it to edit it on the fly- are there any that offer this? in drupal and wordpress you have to wait for the admin pages to load and then flick to the public view and it is quite annoying.

thanks

andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla it's possible http://www.joomla.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try [Plone](http://plone.org/), it allows you to edit pages inline (turned off by default).

Answer (score 1):

You did not try very hard to find an answer.

First link on Google. http://opensourcecms.com